# How to use timer-threads and views

Tags: android, multithreading, view

My problem is:
I wrote a little android app, which uses many ImageViews.
Their Images have to be changed in the code.
So far it worked fine, but I wanted to add kind of algorithm showing the right answer (it's a game).
They should appear one after another.

```
public void x (int current,final View v)
{
    c = current;
    if(attached[current])
    {
        apply_change(c);
    }
    if(current < 34)
    {
        if(attached[current+1])
        {
            new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask(){
                public void run(){
                    x(c+1,v);
                }},500);
        }
        else
        {
            x(c+1,v);
        }
    }
    else
        new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask(){
            public void run(){
                //NewGame_Click(v);
                finished = true;
            }},1);
}
```

From these threads I can't change the images of my ImageViews (CalledFromWrongThreadException).
So I tried to do so:

```
while(!finished)
    {
        akt();
    }
```

in my UI Thread.
The problem is, that my akt(); function (it changes the images) runs, but nothing can be seen on the screen of my Debug-Phone before not all of the Timer-Threads are finished.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so what you want is to know how to update ui?

Comment: When I run directly from my ui thread it is no problem. I want to know, why timers block my ui or what is happening in case they don't.

Comment: i don't understand this part " nothing can be seen on the screen of my Debug-Phone before not all of the Timer-Threads are finished."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a handler. Timer task runs on a different thread. So you cannot update ui from it. You should update ui on the main UI Thread. You can either use a handler or runonuithread inside the timer tak run method to update ui. But i would suggest you to use a handler

```
       Handler m_handler;
       Runnable m_handlerTask ;  
       m_handler = new Handler();
       m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
       {
         @Override 
         public void run() {

                   // do something 
              m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000); // instad of 1000 mention the delay in milliseconds
         }
       };
       m_handlerTask.run();
```

Or use

```
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

              @Override
              public void run(){
                //update ui here

              }
           });
```