# Update UI from GLThread

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to update my UI from the GLThread with a handler. I have read that everything in "handleMessage" will be performed in the UI Thread but I still get this exception:

```
05-31 09:22:55.653: E/AndroidRuntime(26273): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Here is my handler:

```
public class VideoPlayerCallback implements Handler.Callback {

        public static final int PLAY = 0;
        public static final int STOP = 1;
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if(msg.what == VideoPlayerCallback.PLAY) {
                ARVideoTemplate videoTemp = (ARVideoTemplate) msg.obj; 
                String uriPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/raw/"+videoTemp.getFileName();
                updateVideo(uriPath); // UI Actions
                return true;        
            }
            else if(msg.what == VideoPlayerCallback.STOP){
                updateVideo(null); // UI Actions
                return true;
            }
            return false;    
        }       
    }
```

Then something like this to put this handler to my GLRenderer:

```
Handler player = new Handler(new VideoPlayerCallback());
((ARGLSurfaceView) mGLSurfaceView).setVideoView(player);
```

And the call from GLRenderer:

```
Message msg = Message.obtain(mVideoPlayer);
msg.obj = video;
msg.what = VideoPlayerCallback.PLAY;
this.mVideoPlayer.dispatchMessage(msg);
```

What should I change to access the ui thread properly?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you cannot update ui from a background thread use runonuithread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822534/how-to-use-timer-threads-and-views/16822744#16822744. Check the runonuithread part of the answer. You should update ui on the UI thead.

Comment: ok, I will try rundonuithread but I don't understand why the handler doesn't work. Many people suggest to use a handler..

Comment: you can also use a handler. that should not be problem. But make sure you don't update ui on the background thread

Comment: I only update the UI in handleMessage... that should be in UI thread. But I get the exception exactly in this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my fault. I have to call

```
this.mVideoPlayer.sendMessage(msg);
```

instead of dispatchMessage(msg). Then my handler runs on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that callback-subclassing you are doing, but a handler should work fine, just two things to do:

- You create the handler on the thread that  it should post code to.
- You use the handler.post()-method to post he source to the UI thread, like this:

```java
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        drawStuffToScreen();
    }
});
```